# Why am I getting SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module, when trying to import a CSS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, import

I'm using Firefox 75.0. My file structure looks like this:

[image]

A at top of my index.js file, I have :

```
import "./styles.css";
import ScrollBooster from "scrollbooster";
// go ahead and change some library source code!
// import ScrollBooster from "../libs/scrollbooster";
```

When I try to open index.html, it logs an error saying: **SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module**, pointing to the CSS import. If I remove the CSS import, then it throws the same error, this time pointing to `ScrollBooster from "scrollbooster";`

Why is this happening?

PS : Here's the whole code: https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollbooster-examples-2nn7h?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Is your **index.js** a module?

Comment: I just downloaded this folder : https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollbooster-examples-2nn7h?file=/src/index.js . How is it possible that it runs on the website but not on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the code in sand box and dont see any import issues as mentioned in the console

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble running it on your local machine I would double check your import path.

By the looks of that sandbox code it's importing based on a path specified for their website. When you import on your local machine just ensure that it's taking the correct path to the files that you've downloaded.

Just like the `./styles.css` import is based off of the working folder for your project. The `import ScrollBooster from "scrollbooster"` could be the problem. When hovering it shows `module "/sandbox/node_modules/@types/scrollbooster/index"` as the path. Try changing it to an import similar to the styles.css one potentially.

I did not see any errors, like Ajay Reddy, when I checked that code on the link.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML file is a part of npm package. In order to run the server, you would need to start the server through npm.
First, to install all dependencies (required only once), run:

```
npm install
```

Then to start the server, run:

```
npm start
```

Then from your browser, visit http://localhost:1234